# Effectively parsing plain language paragraphs

Tags: nlp, theory

Ideally if there's an existing solution you know of please let me know, but some brief googling didnt turn up much, though I may not have been using the right keywords in my search.

What I'd like to do is take in a paragraph of text and return an array of keywords the program thinks that paragraph might be about.

I considered maybe finding all the nouns and gerunds by using a database of nouns and searching the paragraph for each one, but that seems terribly inefficient with upwards of a million nouns in English.

Wasn't sure what to tag this other than theory.

Comment: What about counting each word's appearance frequency in the paragraph and then return the most frequent words, applying some filtration to exclude articles and so on?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis